# Difference of sizeof(float) C++

Tags: c++, sizeof

I'm new to C++ and I am developing an equation in context of the following code:

```
fprintf(stderr," inp.width*inp.height*ref.width*ref.height  %lld -------->", 2*3 * (long long int)sizeof(float));
```

which prints **24**. Why it is always multiplied by 4?

Someone please explain me what `(long long int)sizeof(float))` does?

Comment: Going beyond that, `%lld` should be `%zu` and the `(long long int)` removed.

Comment: So, float on your machine takes 4 times as much space as a char, which is very common on a lot of machines(x86, arm, and others). What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(float)` evaluates to the number of bytes used by the compiler to represent an object of type `float`. The type of the value returned by the `sizeof` operator is `size_t`. The preceding `(long long int)` casts the value of `sizeof(float)` to the type `long long int`. It doesn't change the value since the value is just `4` in your compiler, which can be easily represented by `long long int`.

The purpose of casting to `long long int` appears to be to allow the use of the format specifier `"%lld"`.

Answer (score 0):

The `sizeof` operator returns the amount of `bytes` that the type or the variable/arrays are in memory. For this example `sizeof(float)` will return 4 bytes as the type `float` is 4 bytes in memory. So when you do `2*3*(long long int)sizeof(float)`, it will return `24`.

Answer (score 0):

On most architectures, `sizeof(float)` is always 4.

Casting to `(long long int)` is necessary to match the format parameter of `%lld` - the multiplication will automatically convert the result to the largest of the operand types. In this case, since the expected value isn't going to be larger than a regular `int` can hold, you could have skipped the cast and used `%d` instead.